# convergence of $\int_{x=0}^{\infty}x^{-\frac{M-1}{2}-N}(1-e^{-x})^{M-1}e^{-x}dx$

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I am trying to study the convergence of 
$$\int_{x=0}^{\infty}x^{-\frac{M-1}{2}-N}(1-e^{-x})^{M-1}e^{-x}dx,$$
where $M$ and $N$ are positive integers.

I've tried some $M$ and $N$, and it seems that when $M>N$ the integral converges, o.w. it does not.

But there is a way to prove or dis prove it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start.

Around zero,
$1-e^{-x}
=1-(1-x+x^2/2-x^3/6+...)
=x-x^2/2+x^3/6-...
=x(1-x/2+x^2/6-...)
$
so the integral up to $c$,
where $c$ is small,
is about

$\begin{array}\\
\int_{0}^{c}x^{-\frac{m-1}{2}-n}(1-e^{-x})^{m-1}e^{-x}dx
&=\int_{0}^{c}x^{-\frac{m-1}{2}-n}(x(1-x/2+x^2/6-...))^{m-1}(1-x)dx\\
&\approx \int_{0}^{c}x^{-\frac{m-1}{2}-n}x^{m-1}(1-x/2+x^2/6-...))^{m-1}(1-x)dx\\
&\approx  \int_{0}^{c}x^{\frac{m-1}{2}-n}(1-(m-1)x/2)(1-x)dx\\
&\approx \int_{0}^{c}x^{\frac{m-1}{2}-n}dx\\
&= \frac{x^{\frac{m-1}{2}-n+1}}{\frac{m-1}{2}-n+1}\big|_{0}^{c}\\
&= \frac{x^{\frac{m+1}{2}-n}}{\frac{m+1}{2}-n}\big|_{0}^{c}\\
\end{array}
$

For this to converge,
we must have
$\frac{m+1}{2}-n
> 0
$.

Comment: @ marty cohen, thanks! Should it be $\frac{m+1}{2}-n>0$ instead of $\ge$?

Comment: You are right, because of the denominator. I'll change it. Thanks.